# Confluent Kafka python producer poll() method

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I am newbie on Kafka and while reading docs stumbled upon flush() and poll() methods. According to my understanding, flush method flushes the producer buffer to send all events to broker.

But what exactly do poll method do? According to docs:
`Polls the producer for events and calls the corresponding callbacks (if registered).`

So, if I don't poll won't the producer send any message to the broker?

I am completely lost here. Can anyone please help me understand working of this poll method and why is it mandatory to poll. Also, I was previously seeing kafka-python library which has concepts like linger.ms which makes sure the producer sends events to broker after this time.

I haven't found any such parameter in confluent kafka python library. So, is it due to absence of such configuration that we need to poll compulsorily?

Comment: `linger.ms` just tells the separate producer thread to "linger" for at least the time specified by "linger.ms" (in milliseconds) before actually sending a block of messages. (Usually it's up to 5 by default if idempotency is enabled.) Without this the producer will try to send 1 message as soon as it has 1 message to send in its dispatch queue.

Answer (score 0):

Producer poll is an internal function called by produce for the delivery callbacks. You wouldn't call it directly

flushing or closing is what actually send to the broker, yes

> why is it mandatory to poll

For a consumer it's mandatory. I've not seen this documented anywhere for the producer

> haven't found any such parameter in confluent kafka python library

Because it's using librdkafka internally, and that's documented separately.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/librdkafka/html/md_CONFIGURATION.html

Comment: I don't completely agree with this answer, and I have added some further details in another answer. If you disagree with anything I have written there (and I hope you do because I know you know some things about Kafka which I don't yet know) please add comments

Comment: On this answer specifically, things I disagree with: "You wouldn't call it [`producer.poll()`] directly". This isn't correct. You **have** to call it directly to get it to run your callback functions, if you have registered any.

Comment: "flushing or closing is what actually send to the broker" - This is also not correct. Calling `produce()` puts a message in the producers pending buffer. It will asynchronously dispatch those messages. What it will then **not** do by itself is call the callback functions. Calling `flush()` followed by `close()` is just a safe way to shut down a producer. `flush` repeatedly calls poll emptying the buffer and presumably also firing off callbacks. (I don't know about that latter part for certain.) Close (I assume) terminates the network connection

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, of all places, [in the Rust documentation](https://docs.rs/rdkafka/0.36.2/rdkafka/producer/index.html), which states:

> If poll is not called, or not frequently enough, the producer will return a RDKafkaErrorCode::QueueFull error and it won’t be able to send any other message until more delivery events are processed via poll. The QueueFull error can also be returned if Kafka is not able to receive the messages quickly enough.

This is the documentation for the Rust client which uses `librdkafka`. The Rust client is a wrapper around this C implementation.

This information is only relevant if the Python client is also a wrapper around `librdkafka`. And indeed it is, as stated in this [documentation](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python):

> **Reliable** - It's a wrapper around `librdkafka` (provided automatically via binary wheels) which is widely deployed in a diverse set of production scenarios. It's tested using the same set of system tests as the Java client and more. It's supported by Confluent.

I have verified the following with the **Python Client**:

- **if you do not call** `producer.poll()` **any callbacks you have registered will not be triggered**
- so it is clear that in order for those callbacks to fire, you **have** to call `producer.poll()`
- **but** what happens if you **do not** call it?
- Assuming the documentation is correct, eventually your producer will fill its buffer full of pending events and crash

**Let's look at an example:**

```
producer.produce(
    topic=topic_name,
    key=message_key,
    value=message_value,
    on_delivery=delivery_callback,
)
```

The important part here is `on_delivery=delivery_callback`, which registers a callable thing as a delivery callback for this particular message.

- Doing this must use some memory in the producer buffer, otherwise the producer would not "remember" which callback function to fire when a particular offset is reported as having been delivered to the broker
- Because the producer buffer is a fixed and finite size, it is presumably the case that if you do **not** call `producer.poll()` **ever** then your producer will eventually run out of buffer memory and crash
- I have not actually tested this specific case but it is certainly the case that your producer can run out of buffer space. I have observed this happening in the context of transactions being left open for too long, and too much data being produced into the producer
- Also recall the producer runs in its own separate thread, calling produce only moves data into a waiting buffer
- It seems that committing an open transaction has the same side effect as calling poll, or more accurately `producer.flush()` (ie, flushing messages out of the buffer)
- This can be inferred due to the fact committing is a slow operation. It requires a lot of synchronization between different hosts, and that synchronous behavior (rather than asynchronous behavior of normal Kafka operation) means it is comparatively very slow as little bits of network latency add up significantly
- I have also done some testing to count the number of times the registered callback function fires vs the number of times produce is called. After a transaction is committed, both of these numbers match
- The same is presumably true if you do not use transactions and call `flush()` instead
- From this I would guess if you never call `poll()` your producer will eventually fill its buffer and die, I doubt I observed the above described behavior just because I was using transactions
- Also consider this: Even if the producer is working to dispatch messages correctly, and the message data does not cause the buffer to fill up, it still has to remember what functions to call as callbacks, and this will still use some space in the buffer (presumably less than the messages themselves)
- We can infer that the minimum amount of data required to be retained is a message offset and a function pointer or reference. I am not sure how many bytes that is in the librdkafka layer. It is presumably 64 bits for the offset and maybe a few 10s of bytes for a Python object reference. It might be another 64 bits for a pointer

What happens if you don't specify add a callback to the `producer.produce()` function call?

- I don't know exactly, it could be that no additional data is stored and your producer will therefore not crash due to the buffer filling up
- Or it might be that even after a message is dispatched the producer still retains some data until `poll()` is called, and therefore given enough running time the producer will still eventually crash

## Instructive exercise:

Write a Kafka program with 1x consumer and 1x producer which copies data from one topic to another.

- See how fast you can get it to run
- Find out what slows it down (bottlenecks like commits, flush, long producer poll times)
- Change the producer/consumer/topic/broker config to find out how different parameters affect things
- Find out how much data has to be on the topic before you can overflow the buffer and crash the producer
- Find a way to prevent that from happening

You may need to write a helper program to generate random data to your input topic, to ensure you have enough data to break something. (A gigabyte should do.)

Finally note that **there is no easy way to test and compare the different behaviors in the following scenarios:**

- producing with no callback registered
- vs producing with a callback registered

In other words, how would you test if the latter option causes the producer buffer to fill up faster? The answer is you can't!

- You may suggest produce messages at a low message rate and for a long enough period of time. The idea being that messages will be dispatched by the producer thread, but if `poll()` is not called then the buffer will still eventually fill up, despite the fact that the number of messages in the producer waiting queue is low.
- However it is obvious this experiment would be inconclusive. How "slow" is slow enough? We don't know. There is no way to query how many messages are in the producers dispatch queue.